# Clicking on a link via selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to do some webscraping via Selenium.  My question is very simple: How do you find a link and then how do you click on it?  For instance: The following is the HTML that I am trying to web-scrape:

```html
<td bgcolor="#E7EFF9">
  <a href="javascript:selectDodasaDetdasdasy(220011643,'Kdasdası');" target="_self">
   Details
  </a>
</td>
```

So, as you can see the word "Details" is a link.

How can I find that link using Selenium and click on it?

Comment: I tried the suggested idea on a td_element after I got the td element via td_tag = tr_tag.find_element_by_tag_name('td'). When I call the find_element_by_link_text('details') I get the selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException error with the message unable to locate element locate element {''method'': ''link text'', ''selector'': ''details''}'

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use [`find_element_by_link_text`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text):

For example:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# <...>

link = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Details')
```

To Click on it, just call click method:

```py
link.click()
```

Comment: so thanks, but how can I call on that on a td object like the above ? For instance I have elem_query_result = driver.find_element_by_id('sorgudadasdsac') then I have tr_tag= elem_query_result.find_element_by_tag_name('tr') then I have td_tag = tr_tag.find_element_by_tag_name('td') and I want to call find_element_by_link_text('Details') on the td_tag, but it gives me the following error: unable to locate element {''method'': ''link text'', ''selector'': ''details''}'

Comment: @canbaran, once you find your element, you can call again the function over it. In example, once you do `td_tag = tr_tag.find_element_by_tag_name('td')`, you can do `td_tag.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")` to find links on it.

Answer (score 2):

Then you can try something like this.

```
for (int i=0; i&lttd.length(); i++){
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Details')])[i]").click()
        }
```

Comment: cant I call find_element_by_link on a td tag?

Comment: there are many links with the text ''details'', I am looping over the tags and when I am inside a td, I want to call find_element_by_link_text on that td tag. does that make sense ?

Comment: I did try and I appreciate it but it gives all the links. As said, I am looping over them, I want to be able to open each one through the loop

Comment: see if there are many links with the text "details", then by link_text you won't be able to find its unique property, you need to search for a unique identifier.

Comment: check I've modified my answer, put this line of code in a for loop and iterate on variable 'i' it should work fine then.

Comment: I see thanks, but specifically cant you call this find_element_by_link on a td_tag ? when I do that I pasted the error I get

Comment: I am sorry but you are not exactly answering my question. I will go ahead and accept the original answer and make it plural driver.find_element'S'_by_link_text and change the way I tackle my problem. We can start a different thread if desired or continue the discussion over emails

Answer (score 0):

You can try to click link by using xpath locator
e.g.

```
link=driver.find_element_by_xpath(.//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/h4)

link.click()
```

Answer (score -2):

One thing is missed by everyone. Its a list by the below statement. You need to take select an element from this list.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Details')
```

If you check

```
for i in driver.find_element_by_link_text('Details')
    i.click()
```

BINGO :-)

Comment: Have you tried your own code?
First, `find_by_element` returns a webdriver element, in case you try to click everything iterating it, you'll surely get error because strings or others doesn't have the click attribute. Maybe you are talking about `find_elements` (note the s, plural), so you get a list of webdriver elements that you can click()

Comment: @petezurich, what's the purpose of editing something that is wrong?

Comment: @erm3nda To improve overall site quality? To give any answer a fair chance of feedback e.g. the specific and with good reason critical feedback that you kindly provided?