# want to click on the particular link in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

suppose if you click on the contact us page ,in that page you want to click on the india in the list of the countries present in the contact us page.How we can write code for this in selenium

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597735/clicking-on-a-link-via-selenium-in-python. Also , while posting queries post what is problem you are facing , some reference code snippets

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("contact us")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("India")).click();
```

Here instead of Id use can use Xpath,Text,CSS also