# How to click/use a link parsed from Beautiful Soup in python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hello I'm a beginner in python and I'm confused on where to go from here

How do I interact/click with a specific link after using bs4 to search for it? So in my script I use bs4 to search through links, that can be clicked on in the the webpage, with specific keywords so I click on the right product.

```
onSale = False  # Set while loop variable
shoeName = 'moon'  # Set keyword to look for
browser = webdriver.Chrome()


browser.get(r'https://www.nike.com/launch/?s=upcoming')  # Get URL to scan
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')  # Convert URL to a soup object


while onSale is False:  # Create loop to keep checking inventory

for link in soup.find_all('a', class_=r'card-link d-sm-b'):
    shoeCode = str((link.get('href', None), link.get_text()))
    compareName = re.sub("[^\w]", " ", shoeCode.lower()).split()  # Takes the link and converts it into a string

    if shoeName in compareName:  # Checks to see if the keyword is used

       # Interact/Click link

    else:
        print(shoeCode)

        continue
```

Once the proper link has been found how do I use it to interact with the website? Do I use selenium, urllib, and or requests? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selenium to click the links, you can see how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597735/clicking-on-a-link-via-selenium-in-python#18597860). Or, after fetching the page with requests (forget urllib) and extracting urls with bs4, you can `requests.get('your_example_url')` it and fetch the results again.

Comment: Thank you for the link and answer I appreciate it!