# selecting element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a html tag like this :

```
<a target="_blank" href="//www.phptravels.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">                                             <small>http://www.phptravels.net</small>  </a>
```

I want to select this link using selenium webdriver . how can i do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clicking on a link via selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597735/clicking-on-a-link-via-selenium-in-python)

Comment: @DeepakBaliyan Which language binding are you using? Can you recheck the HTML you you have provided as the `<a>` tag isn't closed. Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the link text in xpath. Syntax is:

```
//*[text()='link text']
```

Comment: You can use back-tick to format the code in your answer