# Get full HTML for page with dynamic expanded containers with python

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, expandable

I am trying to pull the full HTML from ratemyprofessors.com however at the bottom of the page, there is a "Load More Ratings" button that allows you to see more comments.

I am using requests.get(url) and beautifulsoup, but that only gives the first 20 comments. Is there a way to have the page load all the comments before it returns?

Here is what I am currently doing that gives the top 20 comments, but not all of them.

```
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    comments = []
    for j in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'Comments__StyledComments-dzzyvm-0 dEfjGB'}):
        comments.append(j.text)
```

Comment: Using the dev network console, track what request is being made to load more, and then make a similar request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is more of an HTML parser for static pages than renderer for more dynamic web apps.

You could achieve what you want using a headless browser via Selenium by rendering the full page and repeatedly clicking the more link until there is no more to load.

Example: [Clicking on a link via selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597735/clicking-on-a-link-via-selenium)

Since you're already using Requests, another option that might work is Requests-HTML which also supports dynamic rendering By calling `.html.render()` on the response object.

Example: https://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/index.html#requests_html.HTML.render

Reference: [Clicking link using beautifulsoup in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679480/clicking-link-using-beautifulsoup-in-python)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had to change around my code, but using selenium was what I needed to do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidHafen Glad to hear it.  Feel free to vote and/or accept the answer if it helped solve your problem.