# How do I click on this link using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

[The link that I want to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM4rL.png)
I am new to Selenium. Spent almost an hour on this. What is the correct way to click on this link with Selenium?

Comment: What link ? What have you tried till now ?

Comment: Added the image. Check now. I was trying xpath and css selectors

Comment: I see this is a moneycontrol link.... You can try driver.findElement(By.linkText("Annual Report")).click()
Refer https://devqa.io/selenium-click-link-by-href/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597735/clicking-on-a-link-via-selenium

Comment: Actually you can get the ```link``` and then use ```driver.navigate(link)``` to move into that page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below xpath using text() or title

- Xpath=//a[text()='Annual Report']
- Xpath=//a[@title='Annual Report ']
- Xpath=//a[contains(@title,'Annual Report')]